# Issue moving ear from JBoss EAP 5.1 to 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to move an ear file from JBoss 5.1 EAP to 6.1.  I'm getting this issue when I try to use an EJB:

```
NamingException JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.my.ear.my.war:main" from Service Module Loader
13:34:14,304 INFO  [stdout]  javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.my.ear.my.war:main" from Service Module Loader
13:34:14,304 INFO  [stdout]          at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
13:34:14,304 INFO  [stdout]          at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)
13:34:14,305 INFO  [stdout]
```

The code this error comes from is:

```
new InitialContext("{java.naming.provider.url=corbaloc::server:port, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory}");
```

This worked fine on JBoss 5.1, but not 6.1.  I checked and that class exists on 6.1, not sure why I am getting this error.

EDIT: Also, this is moving from JDK 6 to JDK 7.

Comment: I'd recommend the jboss forums for this.

Comment: If you are using eap then I would recommend you contacting Red Hat JBoss support directly.

Answer (score 1):

- Since EAP is so modularized that sometimes it does not even pick up the jre libraries. We need to mention it in jboss-deployment-structure.xml so that the application does not fail while deploying.
- You need to create jboss-deployment-structure.xml in EAR_Name\META-INF with the following content:

  ```
  <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

    <sub-deployment name="WAR_Name.war">
              <exclusions>                              
              <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
              </exclusions>
          <dependencies>
              <system>
                  <paths>
                      <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/datatype"/>
                      <path name="com/sun/jndi/rmi" />
                      <path name="com/sun/jndi/rmi/registry"/>
                  </paths>
              </system>
      </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
  ```